# Using MySQL Databases and PHP to Populate forms

Tags: php, mysql

I am contemplating taking the next step with my PHP applications and making the option fields dynamic. That would open the doors for more automation.

I have drop downs throughout my project, they are used to select a specific user and I update them manually when a new user is added (which is also a manual process). But if i take the first step and make these drop downs become populated by a MySQL Database, then i can move on to dynamic user creation.

I know how I can achieve this, but I am curious about some other alternatives (If there is any).

Here is what I would do..

```
$query = ** MySQL Select * From Database Query **

echo '<select name="usernames">';

while($row == mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
     echo '<option>' . $row['username'] . '</option>';
}

echo '</select>';
```

So my questions is, would you do this differently? And why? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing will work fine. I like to make it into a function so that if I ever need that dropdown on another page I dont have to write a lot of code over again.

```
function userDD()
{
   $query = ** MySQL Select * From Database Query **
   $html = '<select name="usernames">';

   while($row == mysql_fetch_array($query))
   {
        $html .= '<option>' . $row['username'] . '</option>';
   }

   $html .= '</select>';

   return $html;
}
```

This code does exactly what your code does except it doenst use echo. Instead you use a variable ($html) to store all of the data then when you are done you return it.

Comment: Can you show me an example of how this can be used in a function? I know how to make a function but I'm not sure how it can be applied here. It would help me a lot.

Comment: I just added an example of your code in a function. You do everything the same except you store everything in a variable instead of echoing it. When everything is done you just return the html.

Answer (score 1):

Your way is fine, but two things need to be changed:
- **Run [htmlentities](http://php.net/htmlentities)() or [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars)() on all echoed HTML to avoid XSS.** Unless you already sanitized it at database entry time but I find this practice silly.
- Add a `value` attribute to each `<option>` tag, otherwise you won't be able to retrieve the username selected. I suggest using the username's corresponding ID or something else that's unique to that user. If it's a string, use htmlentities/htmlspecialchars on it too.

Comment: This is not true. If there is no value="xyz on each <option>, it will return the text from the selected option. However, I do agree that providing an option (normally something like an ID) is the best way forward.

Answer (score 1):

### php file

```
$users = getUsers();

include('template.tpl');
```

### template

```
<select name="username">
<?php foreach( $users as $user ): ?>
    <li><?= e( $user['username'] ) ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

e is a function that escapes strings to prevent xss attacks

Comment: @chris Also, the alternative loop syntax shown here makes this code much easier to read.  Inlining HTML code into your PHP statements is bad news bears.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't put an SQL query in the same document as my output...

I'd create a document containing all SQL queries, in functions, and include that file. Just to keep things seperated.